# (Edited)VBA Select files with specific letters and numbering out of identical names with added variation

Tags: vba, excel, challenge-response

I'm starting to work with macros and I have a list of over 100 files to open in VBA with names such as:
Mark001.xls Mark_001_initial.xls
Mark001_improvement.xls
Mark002.xls
Mark002_initial.
Marc002_Improvement.xls
Pol001.xls
...

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim FilesToOpen

FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (FileFilter:="EXLS Files(*.xls), *.xls," & "Mark??? Files (Mark???.xls), Mark???.xls", MultiSelect:=True, Title:="EXLS Files To Open")

End Sub
```

This opens a window to select files, however there are no files to select,it doesn't identify them

There are also identical files in .txt format, but I only need to open the ones that are of type Mark001.xls, the larger names are irrelevant.

Also I need to copy them to a different folder. I tried to use OpenFile, SerchFile, and selectFile applications but had no success.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Try reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to increase the likelihood that you'll get an answer. Also, this isn't a code-writing service, so post what you've got (just edit your post and add it in) and pinpoint where it's failing, and somebody will stop by to help you fix it.

Comment: Use wildcards `Mark_???.TXT` Search google on how to use wildcards with `DIR` to open files from a particular folder.

Comment: Thank you @FreeMan for clarifying the format.

Comment: Thanks @Siddharth Rout for the MARK_???.TXT it was what i was looking for. However the code is not working yet. The DIR command is only for sellecting one file as I understand but I will have to go through over a 100 of them and need to open each of them as worksheets in one workbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Application.GetOpenFilename` wildcards work only for the file extension as in

```
FileFilter:="Excel files (*.xl*)," & "*.xl*"
```

That will return all *.xls and *.xlsx files

Other Options:

```
Application.FileDialog (msoFileDialogOpen Or msoFileDialogFilePicker)
```

.

```
Sub openWildFile()     'use params to make it generic: "ByVal partialName As String"

    Const partialName   As String = "*Mark_"
    Const partialExt    As String = "*.xl*"

    Dim selectedFile    As String, dlg As Object        'A 3rd option is to use APIs

    Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen) 'Or (msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With dlg

        .Title = "Select " & partialName & " File"

        With .Filters
            .Clear
            .Add partialName & " Files", partialExt
        End With

        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .InitialFileName = partialName & partialExt

        If (.Show <> 0) Then selectedFile = Trim(.SelectedItems.Item(1))

    End With
End Sub
```

.

To copy files use this:

```
FileCopy SourceFile, DestinationFile    ' Copy source file to target
```

Comment: Thank you so much `@paul bica`!!! I made a small change in `.InitalFileName=partialName` Otherwise the extension part `*` would overwrite the boundaries of the partial name, It would be complete name instead of partial. Also, Why is **If 0 then** part needed?

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. The **If 0 then** part is for you to choose between the 2 types of dialogs - you can change it to **If 1 then** to see the other one, but they are similar so I'll just take that part out